# Enable Irony-mode

Tags: auto-complete-mode, c++, irony-mode

I'm having some trouble trying to activate irony-mode.

So i followed the steps:

1. My version of gcc is 5.3.0 so I installed -> clang 3.7.1
2. I installed CMake
3. Then irony from MELPA
4. After that added this configuration to my init.el:

   ```el
   (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
   (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
   (add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'irony-mode)

   ;; replace the `completion-at-point' and `complete-symbol' bindings in
   ;; irony-mode's buffers by irony-mode's function
   (defun my-irony-mode-hook ()
     (define-key irony-mode-map [remap completion-at-point]
       'irony-completion-at-point-async)
     (define-key irony-mode-map [remap complete-symbol]
       'irony-completion-at-point-async))
   (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'my-irony-mode-hook)
   (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
   ```
5. Then I was asked to install irony-server,so I did it.And....nothing!

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you please explain the problem in more detail. What does not work? Does `irony-mode` not turn on? Do the things in your `my-irony-mode-hook` not get effective? Above 2 things happen but something else does not happen?

Comment: I wrote a demo project,i added (#include "myHeader.h"),and when i declare  some objects it doesnt auto-complete methods and such...

Comment: And yes i have all files in the same folder.

Comment: Did you create a compilation database? Should be a JSON file in your project root. CMake can output them, otherwise Bear (Build EAR) is a good choice.